# Different PTS values in ffmpeg and MP4 CTS values obtained using ctts and stts

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, mp4, pts

I have been studying PTS values in .mp4 media files. PTS for video stream can be extracted from ffmpeg CLI using

```
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i  -vf "showinfo" -f null -
```

For a sample .mp4 I have downloaded from the internet shows the following output.

```
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] config in time_base: 1/30, frame_rate: 30/1
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:    58852 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:49058BA3 plane_checksum:[E852D7DE 07E2B7D4 EA12FBD3] mean:[75 123 124] stdev:[52.7 4.8 11.7]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00]   side data - User Data Unregistered:
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] UUID=dc45e9bd-e6d9-48b7-962c-d820d923eeef
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] User Data=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
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] 
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
        encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-01-23T22:02:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
          vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
          encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 wrapped_avframe
      Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2018-01-23T22:02:00.000000Z
          handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
          vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
          encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 pcm_s16le
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   1 pts:      1 pts_time:0.0333333 pos:   149037 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:2005D769 plane_checksum:[92BD4F7B 3501F48D 0CAA9352] mean:[75 124 124] stdev:[52.5 4.7 11.7]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   2 pts:      2 pts_time:0.0666667 pos:   139805 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:09AFB702 plane_checksum:[3E62184D 9D0A0753 8BF09762] mean:[75 124 124] stdev:[52.4 4.6 11.5]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   3 pts:      3 pts_time:0.1     pos:   157017 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:99F05FA9 plane_checksum:[FFA84276 7A3D6D59 0290AFCB] mean:[75 124 124] stdev:[52.2 4.5 11.3]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   4 pts:      4 pts_time:0.133333 pos:   117259 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:00935CD8 plane_checksum:[F81E097E 5F17005D B01452FD] mean:[74 124 124] stdev:[52.2 4.5 11.3]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   5 pts:      5 pts_time:0.166667 pos:   197428 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:30E77B4C plane_checksum:[393DAA75 DFA88599 E2164B2F] mean:[74 124 125] stdev:[52.3 4.4 11.0]
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
    [Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x3741c00] n:   6 pts:      6 pts_time:0.2     pos:   187073 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:BD5C25BC plane_checksum:[CC66DD70 F4ACA5DB 955DA253] mean:[75 124 125] stdev:[52.2 4.4 10.8]
```

As seen above, the output shows a starting PTS of 0 for 1st frame. However, I was looking at ctts, and stts entries in the MP4 headers with the help of [ParseTimingInfoInMp4.py](https://app.box.com/s/pg3c2apw2o890wn72v54wt546xb9r8yt). This shows a different PTS (e.g.,  0.0667s) for the 1st frame as seen below.

```
    ftyp    size              32
    mvhd    size             108
    iods    size              42
    tkhd    size              92
    edts    size              36
    mdhd    size              32
    Trak type:  b'vide'
    Video Trak Number 0 found
    video track timescale is 30
    mdhd    size              32
    hdlr    size              54
    vmhd    size              20
    dinf    size              36
    stsd    size             195
    stts size  2944  ctts size  2944
    0    dts = 0.0000 s,    pts = 0.0667 s,    diff in ms    66.67
    1    dts = 0.0333 s,    pts = 0.2000 s,    diff in ms    166.67
    2    dts = 0.0667 s,    pts = 0.1333 s,    diff in ms    66.67
    3    dts = 0.1000 s,    pts = 0.1000 s,    diff in ms    0.00
    4    dts = 0.1333 s,    pts = 0.1667 s,    diff in ms    33.33
    5    dts = 0.1667 s,    pts = 0.3333 s,    diff in ms    166.67
    6    dts = 0.2000 s,    pts = 0.2667 s,    diff in ms    66.67
    7    dts = 0.2333 s,    pts = 0.2333 s,    diff in ms    0.00
    8    dts = 0.2667 s,    pts = 0.3000 s,    diff in ms    33.33
    9    dts = 0.3000 s,    pts = 0.4333 s,    diff in ms    133.33
    10    dts = 0.3333 s,    pts = 0.3667 s,    diff in ms    33.33
```

[MP4Analyser](https://github.com/essential61/mp4analyser/tree/master) shows the following entries for stss, ctts, and edts-> for video track.
[image: stss entries for video track]
[image: ctts entries for video track]
[image: edts -> elst entry for video track]

The sample file I have been using can be found in [Sample mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MCuLO21rM9jOtcoVIg_9OFl4vdwv2zi0/view?usp=drive_link).

Can someone please help me to understand

1. why the PTS values shown in ffmpeg are different from PTS derived from stss and ctts?
2. What is the correct process in deriving PTS from stts, ctts and edts entries in MP4 header?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg will, by default, offset pts to start from 0. Add `-copyts` to avoid this.

Next, the decoder will reorder frames in presentation order, which will be different from storage order. This applies when the stream has B-frames.

Edit list adjustment can get complex, so I'll address the two simple cases: an initial dwell is applied as an offset to all timestamps. An initial edit (trimming of the start of the media) leads to negative timestamps for all samples before the edit start point.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, does ffmpeg compute its PTS for .mp4 by using stts, and ctts values? Or does it use PTS values embedded in PES? The issue is, if I shift PTS using -itsoffset, I don't see a change in stts, and ctts based timestamps (i.e, stts[n] + ctts[n]).

Comment: MP4 ts are computed from the trak tables only. itsoffset is a CLI option which is after the packet is exported from the demuxer.

Comment: Still trying to understand this. If I use 'ffmpeg -itsoffset 1.25 -i <input.mp4> -i <input.mp4> -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4', I see that video PTS is shifted by 1.25 in output.mp4 when you check this in ffmpeg. But, nothing has changed in (stts + ctts). However, edts->elst entry (segment_duration and media_time) has changed. How are these two values being used to compute PTS that is shown in ffmpeg?

Comment: You're conflating two things: timestamps of packets within ffmpeg's pipeline and stored timestamps in mp4. itsoffset shifts ts once the demuer emits the packet. When the mp4 muxer receives a stream starting with a non-zero ts, it writes a dwell entry in the trak elst. That dwell entry when read as an input (with copyts) is read as a non-zero starting pts.

Comment: Ok, its a bit clear now, thanks. My original concern was that PTS values displayed by ffmpeg, and (stts /tb + ctts / tb) are significantly different, and I cannot find a proper matching between the two. So, if I need to find out start PTS of a stream, can I rely on ffmpeg's PTS output? or is it recommended to compute this manually from mp4's atom values?

Comment: As long as the edit list doesn't have complex edits, you can rely on ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Are there any references/manuals that I use to gather more info on this. I'm still not very clear about the relationship between ffmpeg's PTS, and stts/ctts values I'm seeing. Also, mediainfo inspection reveals completely different set of numbers for "source_delay", which I assume to be the starting PTS of the file.

Comment: BTW, I found another discrepancy between (AVPacket->pts * av_q2d(tb), and AVFrame->pts values. While AVFrame->pts gives me 0 for the input I'm working, AVPacket->pts * av_q2d(tb) gives a -ve number that matches to 'source_delay' element in mediainfo.